# Error loading colour scheme in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

This error appears every time I save file or open a file.

> Error loading colour scheme Packages\User\MonokaiGrayDL.tmTheme: Unable to open Packages\User\MonikaiGray.tmTheme

I searched about it but those solutions are for sublime text 2...please help

Comment: And I don't have Live Css Package.

Comment: Sometimes solutions that work for ST2 will work for ST3 as well. Have you tried something already ?

Comment: Most solutions say the problem is the Live CSS and I don't have it. One solution says it's the parse error of xml but I can't even find that file...

Comment: Did you try to install a theme manually ? I found [this](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/issues/103) if it can help you ...

Comment: Uh..No it still doesn't work

Comment: do you see the same thing when you switch to a different theme, like the built-in Monokai Bright? (`Preferences -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme - Default -> Monokai Bright`)

Comment: yes I have the same situation for every theme

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to put the theme file inside `Packages\Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package`.

Open `Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package` with 7 zip (archive tool-you may use your favorite tool), and drag `Monokai Gray.tmTheme` into it. Then go to Sublime, and click Preferences -> Color Scheme and find Monokai Gray. When you choose the color scheme, it automatically updates the setting with this:

```
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/MonoKai Gray.tmTheme",
```

Note: I am using Sublime 3. I am not able to share my screen shot due to lack of reputation.

Comment: problem solved, thanks/btw, do you know how to solve this problem without drag [tmTheme] files into [Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package]?

Comment: For me I did have it working, but all `js` files didn’t look right, turned out I needed to install `BetterJavascript` from package manager.

Answer (score 41):

```
Menu > Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User> remove the line with `"color_scheme"`.
```

After saving the line was regenerated for me with a reference to a theme that actually exists.

Comment: Cool. It Worked :)

Comment: easiest solution

Comment: It was this simple.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes, a couple of opened files ignores color schemes settings modifications, I had the same bug then ran this in the ST3 console :

```
[ v.settings().erase("color_scheme") for views in [ w.views() for w in sublime.windows() ] for v in views ]
```

This python code is pretty self explanatory.

With this, no need to close/re-open incriminated files for the bugs to go away.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629211/4356183)

Comment: This solution solved my problem, while the approved answer did not solve it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me after installing [Compare Side-By-Side](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side). The error message specified that `SBSCompareTheme.theme` could not be found. I don't remember the exact sequence of events, but I remember that at some point, I uninstalled the plugin, and the error message kept appearing.

It turns out that the theme file was referenced in the `Local/Session.sublime_session` file (`~/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session` under OSX).

I edited that file by hand to remove any reference to the theme file, and the problem went away!

Comment: Thanks - this was my problem.

Comment: It might be obvious, but make sure you open the file with nano or other text editor. Otherwise your changes won't be saved :)

Answer (score 4):

I am using Sublime Text 3.
I remove ColorHighlighter and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem:

My issue was that some packages creates a syntax-specific *.sublime-settings file (Markdown.sublime-settings in my case).

The file is located in Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User.

Comment: ^This was the answer I needed. I removed a theme, and Sublime kept throwing that error (and I didn't want to reinstall the theme).

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me every now and then when my theme in use is being updated via Package Control. Try switching to a different theme, optionally remove and re-install Monokai Gray, then switch back to it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with certain files/syntaxes after deleting a package (MarkdownEditing).

My issue was that some packages creates a syntax-specific `*.sublime-settings` file (`Markdown.sublime-settings` in my case). The file is location in `Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`.

This settings-file overwrites your color-scheme settings elsewhere. Removing it solved the issue.

Comment: I just posted a similar answer on another SO post, I should've read further to find this! In my case, I broke my AppData directory in Win 10 using a GitHub fetch/merge. [Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042341/10059841)

Answer (score 1):

That's easy!
Click Preferences ->Setting-User

you'll find your "color_scheme" attribute is your error message.
change it with a exist ".tmTheme" file.

Answer (score 1):

GO to Preferences->Browse Packages->User->open HTML.sublime-settings
then remove the line with `"color_scheme"` and save it.
if it doesn't work, just open PHP.sublime-settings instead of HTML.sublime-settings and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Sublime.

Sublime 3 here, worked for me after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error for the package [PlainTasks](https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks). By **renaming** the folder **PlainTasks-master** to **PlainTasks** and **restarting** Sublime resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the source code of the .tmTheme file from Github.

Open your non-working .tmTheme file with Sublime text.

Paste contents, save and restart Sublime text.

Answer (score -1):

delete the user and you can fined it in C:\Users\webduang\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages

Answer (score -1):

GO to Preference->package control->package control user setting and paste this code..

```
{
"always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
"bold_folder_labels": true,
"color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme",
"draw_minimap_border": true,
"draw_white_space": "selection",
"font_face": "Source Code Pro Medium",
"font_size": 13,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Markdown",
    "Vintage"
],
"indent_guide_options":
[
    "draw_normal",
    "draw_active"
],
"line_padding_bottom": 3,
"line_padding_top": 3,
"material_theme_accent_orange": true,
"overlay_scroll_bars": 3,
"theme": "Default.sublime-theme",
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
"word_wrap": false
```

}